# How to create an InvocationExpression without parameters

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

There is a lambda.

for example: `(x,y) => F(x*2) + y;`
I need to replace x by constant (eg 5) and get expression `y => F(10) + y;`
For this I want to invoke expression `{5*2}` and put the returned result as 
`F()` method argument.
I do this in order to find method calls with the same arguments

Answer (score 0):

You would need to replace the parameter by the value using an [ExpressionVisitor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expressionvisitor(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public class ParameterReplacerVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private string parameterName;
    private Expression parameterReplacement;

    public static ParameterReplacerVisitor Create<T>(string name, T value)
    {
        return new ParameterReplacerVisitor(name, Expression.Constant(value));
    }

    public ParameterReplacerVisitor(string name, Expression replacement)
    {
        this.parameterName = name;
        this.parameterReplacement = replacement;
    }

    protected override Expression VisitLambda<T>(Expression<T> node)
    {
        // create new lambda expression without the replaced parameter
        return Expression.Lambda(Visit(node.Body), node.Parameters.Where(x => x.Name != parameterName).ToArray());
    }

    protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
    {
        // if we find our parameter by name replace its usage by the constant expression
        return node.Name == parameterName ? parameterReplacement : node;
    }
}
```

if your input expression is:

```
Expression<Func<int, int, int>> func = (x,y) => F(x*2) + y;
```

you can apply the replacer by:

```
var newFunc = (Expression<Func<int, int>>)ParameterReplacerVisitor.Create("x", 5).Visit(func);
```

which will yield the equivalent to:

```
Expression<Func<int, int>> newFunc = y => F(5*2) + y;
```

Actually, you can replace any parameter with any other expression yielding the same type as replacing a parameter by `Expression.Constant` is only a specific case.

Comment: Thank you, @ckuri
another question: suppose I could get an expression. () => F(5*2) + F(20/2). For each method I will have a argument expressions {5 * 2} and {20/2}. How to check the equivalence of arguments? Will I have to compile them?

Comment: That's more complicated. You could write another ExpressionVisitor who would need to compile each parameter-less sub-expression (or if you want to restrict it to function calls just consider/overwrite VisitMember) and compare their return values. However, this can get inperformant for complex/many expressions.